# Swift: regex function return me empty array

Tags: swift, regex, xcode

hello guys i have problem with working regex in swift

i'm using this regex pattern https://regexr.com/3u4on and this works fine in this website

but in swift code it won't work?

can you help with this problem

I'm using this code in swift:

```
func matches(for regex: String, in text: String) -> [String] {

    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex)

        let results = regex.matches(in: text,
                                    range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))
        return results.map {
            String(text[Range($0.range, in: text)!])
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}

var videoButtonWithAtag = self.matches(for: "<a.[^>]*\\bhref\\s*=\\s*\"[^\"]*mp4.*?</a>", in: html)
print(videoButtonWithAtag) // it's empty
```

Comment: try `"<a.[^>]*\\bhref\\s*=\\s*\"[^\"]*mp4[\\S\\s]*?</a>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `.*` you are missing matches with line break. You should include them as well. So use `[\S\s]*` instead.

This should work:

```
let pattern = "<a.[^>]*\\bhref\\s*=\\s*\"[^\"]*mp4[\\S\\s]*?</a>"
```